# Replace string inside tags?

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a content inside some tags, eg:

```
<p>this it to be replaced</p>
```

I could extract the content between with groups like this, but can i actually replace the group?

```
str = str.replaceAll("<p>([^<]*)</p>", "replacement");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the regex to this:

```
(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)
```

ie

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)", "replacement");
```

This uses a "look behind" and a "look ahead" to assert, but not capture, input before/after the matching (non-greedy) regex

Just in case anyone is wondering, this answer is different to dacwe's: His uses unnecessary brackets. This answer is the more elegant :)

Comment: @dacwe They're *totally* unnecessary. You can use `$0` (which is how you refer to the entire match) which in this case is equivalent to your `$1` :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (positive lookahead and lookbehind) for this:

Change the regex to: `"(?<=<p>)(.*?)(?=</p>)"` and you will be fine.

---

### Example:

```
String str = "<p>this it to be replaced</p>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=<p>)(.*?)(?=</p>)", "replacement"));
```

Output:

```
<p>replacement</p>
```

---

*Note however that if you are parsing HTML you should be using some kind of a HTML parser, often regular expressions is not good enough...*